# Ctrl key not working on ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 two weeks before. I observed that ctrl keys is not working on desktops or in directories but if i open browsers or any softwares ctls keys works? I usually work for ctrl+c, ctrl+v, ctrl+x, ctrl+shift+del. I google'd the reason and found some comments sayig to reset keyboards keys from settings.
But still problem is unsolved. Any solution?